How to detect manual refresh/access token removal from developer console by the user?
I would like to know if it is possible to track HTTP only cookies manual removal from developer console by the user. I know that when the user refreshes the page, changes will occur. Is it possible to track the changes immediately and log the user out as soon as he manually deletes the HTTP only cookie using MERN stack and axios?
I tried using axios interceptors but seems like it does not work
